# Shortcuts for next Tab in Intellij Terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Consider 2 Terminal Tabs in `Intellij`:

[image]

Intellij has shortcuts to *move* `Terminal` tabs left and right:

[image]

A more common operation is simply to *navigate* between the Terminal Tabs.  But I could not find any such shortcut.  Is there a way to do this via the keyboard?

**Update** In response to @PetrRastegaev's suggestion to use the `Window|Editor Tabs|Goto Next/Previous Splitter`: they are not enabled :

[image]

Comment: try "Main menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Goto Next/Previous Splitter"

Comment: @PetrRastegaev I did try the shortcuts for that already.  Sometimes the menu is more reliable so i'll try that now. Checked: the tabs are apparently not considered "splitters" and in fact those options are not enabled: see update to OP